# What is the difference between any and bytes in protobuf 3.0?

Tags: byte, protocol-buffers, message, any

As we know, We can use serialize and unserialize API to convert between `bytes` and message, at the same time, we can use `pack` and `unpack` API to convert between `any` and message. My question is: 
what is the difference between `any` and `bytes` in protobuf 3.0?
Such as store size, speed and so on.

Comment: I think the difference is a `url` that exists in `Any` type but doesn't exists in `bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck up on this issue. But I could not find any answer to this on the net - the Any Type in Proto3 is not well documented online, especially for C++. So, I tried out both of them and the difference lies in what `Any` and `bytes` serialize. While `Any` serializes any arbitrary *Message*, `bytes` serializes any string (in C++).

Here is a code snippet for `Any:

```
// Proto file containing message description for Foo
#include "foo_proto.grpc.pb.h" 

// Proto file containing message description for AnyMessage, 
// which uses google.protobuf.Any
#include "any_proto.grpc.pb.h"

Foo *foo = new Foo(); // Foo is the message defined in "foo_proto.proto"
// ... Set the variables for message Foo

// Pack Foo into 'Any' message type
Any* any = new Any();
any->PackFrom(*foo);

// Use the above 'Any' message to create AnyMessage object
AnyMessage am;
am.set_allocated_object(any);
```

However, for `bytes` you need to pack a string type, instead of the Any object. So, code snippet for `bytes` may look like:

```
// Proto file containing message description for Foo
#include "foo_proto.grpc.pb.h" 

// Proto file containing message description for BytesMessage, 
// which uses the bytes type
#include "bytes_proto.grpc.pb.h"

Foo *foo = new Foo(); // Foo is the message defined in "foo_proto.proto"
// ... Set the variables for message Foo

std::string bytes_string; // Encode the object Foo in this string

// Now, create BytesMessage object
BytesMessage bm;
bm.set_object(bytes_string);
```

I hope this resolves the query raised in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only major difference I can see is that Any adds an extra "@type" field, which is a string URL name of the message that it was packed from.  Example of the URL field it adds:

```
@type = "type.googleapis.com/packagename.messagename"
```

This adds a non-negligible amount of bytes to your message.

Answer (score -1):

There is no protocol difference between 2.0 and 3.0; in theory your data should be identical.

There may be some small differences relating to how defaults and zeros are handled at the library level - in 3.0 "required" and "optional" don't exist, instead: zeros aren't transmitted (everything is effectively optional with a zero default). This means that previously when you might have explicitly assigned a value of zero, it might have been transmitted. Now it will not be. Of course, this also means that non-zero defaults are simply not possible in 3.0.

Emphasis: everything in the second paragraph is at the serializer level, not the protocol level. The protocol is entirely unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for your replying, I want to know the difference between any and bytes in protobuf 3.0.